# Catch sent SMS (Android 2.2)

Tags: android, sms, contentobserver

I know that there are a few Questions here on SO relating to this, but none of them helped me to get this working - capture SMS that being sent.
I am using Android 2.2 (FROYO) on a Samsung phone (if that matters somehow).

I've searched a lot for this on Stackoverflow and realized that I need `ContentObserver` for my request. I'm using Service instead of Activity, so I've registered that `ContentObserver` in my `Service` class, and it looks like this:

```
public class SMSSending extends Service {

private class MyContentObserver extends ContentObserver {

    public MyContentObserver() {
        super(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);      

        Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
        Cursor cur = getBaseContext().getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null);           
        cur.moveToNext();
        String content = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("body"));

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SOME TEXT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    MyContentObserver contentObserver = new MyContentObserver();
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getBaseContext().getContentResolver();
    contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"),true, contentObserver);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SERVICE CREATED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SERVICE STARTED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

As you can see I've put `Toast` in few places so I could see if this is working at all - and unfortunately none of this notifications appear. Also, i tried with putting some code for LogCat but nothing happens.
I've also tried to put `Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms");` instead of `content://sms/sent`
but the application simply doesn't do anything.
Of course, I have permissions in Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortunately, I've managed to work it out, but by using totally different approach. Maybe is this going to help someone in future..

Instead of using ContentObserver (which I still don't know why didn't work) I've created new Thread  and started it after my service has been created and started. So it looks like this:

```
...

final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"); 

...

 public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) { 
        Go();   
    }
    private void Go(){

        new Thread(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() { 

                try {       

                while(true){

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,  null); 

                if(cursor.moveToFirst()){

                    text = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString(); 


                    if(!text.equalsIgnoreCase(actual)){
                        previous = text;
                                    //do what you need..


                    }

                }

                Thread.sleep(60000);
            }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
            } 
    }).start();
```

It's working absolutely stable, even better than with using ContentObserver, having in mind that lot of people had problems with it, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239007/sms-sent-observer-executes-3-times) and some other..