# how to catch the android sms message before factually send

Tags: android, android-service

I Kown how to listen the received sms message by using the android BroadcastReceiver ,but i'm very wondering about how to get the sms content before the device factually send it.
Because some applications will send message without the user's konwing, i want catch this acthion. And show a alertview to the users ,let's them confirm to send the sms or not.Any advice would be welcome!

Comment: refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550178/intercepting-outgoing-sms

Comment: Please read this url 
**http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881173/catch-sent-sms-android-2-2**

Comment: You guys answers are about how to get sms data from the content://sms database, i tried this way and i can read the sended or received sms content from the database , but it's not what i want,i want catch the sms before it send