# Sent SMS observer has double the output

Tags: android, android-service, contentobserver, smsmanager

I'm trying to make an SMS observer for outgoing messages using the `ContentObserver`. The code below works perfectly, but whenever I test this by sending a text message to a colleague, I get the output twice.

The Observer gets registered in a Service, like this:

```
SentSMSObserver sentSMSObserver = new SentSMSObserver(new Handler(), this);
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(sentSMSObserver.CONTENT_SMS_URI, true, sentSMSObserver);
```

Whenever I send a textmessage to my own number, I only get the output once, which is really weird. As a Service is a Singleton (as far as my research has led me to believe), it's quite improbable there is a second instance of my observer.

```
public class SentSMSObserver extends ContentObserver {

    private static final String CONTENT_SMS = "content://sms";
    public final Uri CONTENT_SMS_URI = Uri.parse(CONTENT_SMS);
    private Context context;

    public SentSMSObserver(Handler handler, Context context) {
        super(handler);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_SMS_URI, null, null, null, null);
        try {
            if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String protocol = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("protocol"));
                int type = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("type"));
                if (protocol != null || type != Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.MESSAGE_TYPE_SENT) {
                    return;
                }

                String to = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address"));
                Date now = new Date(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("date")));
                String message = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"));
                Log.e("sentmessage", to + " - " + now + " - " + message);
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

*Logcat:*

```
08-11 14:25:14.292  12574-12574/com.androidfun.smstest E/sentmessage﹕ +(deleted phone n°) - Mon Aug 11 14:25:10 CEST 2014 - Test
08-11 14:25:18.306  12574-12574/com.androidfun.smstest E/sentmessage﹕ +(deleted phone n°) - Mon Aug 11 14:25:10 CEST 2014 - Test
```

Answer (score 0):

Sent messages are also updated with "sent confirmation" and even "delivery confirmation" in some cases. Sending it to yourself, you probably are not getting a "sent confirmation" because it sends and confirms in one step.

See the post here:

[SMS sent observer executes 3 times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239007/sms-sent-observer-executes-3-times?rq=1)